# NPM MySql connection need to be separate in file

Tags: mysql, node.js, npm

I wish to create connection to separate file using npm MySQL. I am expecting to export connection variable or pool variable to each time where I trigger the query. My current approach recreates connection each time if I separate it another file.

//connection.js

```
'use strict';
var mysql            = require('mysql');
var sys              = require('util');
var exec             = require('child_process').exec;
var config           = require('config');
var db_config        = {
    host              : config.get('databaseSettings.db_host'),
    user              : config.get('databaseSettings.db_user'),
    password          : config.get('databaseSettings.db_password'),
    database          : config.get('databaseSettings.database'),
    port              : config.get('databaseSettings.mysqlPORT'),
    multipleStatements: true,
    debug             : ['ComQueryPacket']
};
var restart          = function (callback) {
    console.log('RESTART THE SERVER');
    callback();
    //exec("whoami; pm2 restart dashboard;", callback);
};
var handleDisconnect = function () {
    connection = mysql.createConnection(db_config);
    console.log('\n\n\t--In the handleDisconnect from connection to DB\n');
    connection.connect(function (err) {
        if (err) {
            console.log('--DB CONNECTION ERROR - ');
            setTimeout(handleDisconnect, 2000);
        } else {
            console.log('connection variable created ');
        }
    });
    connection.on('error', function (err) {
        console.log('--DB CONNECTION ERROR - ');
        switch (err.code) {
            case 'PROTOCOL_CONNECTION_LOST':
                handleDisconnect();
                break;
            case 'PROTOCOL_ENQUEUE_AFTER_FATAL_ERROR':
                restart();
                break;
            default:
                throw err;
        }
    });
};
handleDisconnect();
```

This way, I wish to export connection/pool connection from this file.

Comment: Never heard of npm; can you point us at the web page describing its MySQL connectivity?

Comment: https://www.npmjs.com/package/mysql

Answer (score 6, accepted):

## connection.js

```
var mysql = require('mysql');
var db_config = {
   //...
   connectTimeout: 10000 //The milliseconds before a timeout occurs during
                         //the initial connection to the MySQL server.
};
var pool  = mysql.createPool(db_config);

pool.getConnection(function(err, connection) {
  // connected! (unless `err` is set)
});

pool.on('error', function(err) {
  console.log(err.code); // 'ER_BAD_DB_ERROR' 
  // https://www.npmjs.com/package/mysql#error-handling
});

module.exports = pool;
```

## otherfile.js

```
var db = require('./connection.js'); // db is pool

db.query('SELECT 12 AS number', function(err, rows, fields) {
  if (err) throw err;

  console.log('The number is: ', rows[0].solution);
});
```

Comment: How would I recursively reconnect in case db-connection is fail. I tried to implement in my sample code.

Comment: @Sankalp Change `connectTimeout` setting or use `pool.on('error', ...)` to reconnect.

Answer (score 0):

Generally one connection should be held for the lifetime of the calling node.js module.  That is, hang onto your `var mysql` and reuse it until the module terminates (or until you know you don't need it any more).

You could have a "pool", but I would suggest not doing that until you find a need for it.  If/when you do create a pool, I would suggest 10 for connectionLimit.  That's small enough to be not an issue.  Needing more than that would probably indicate inefficiencies elsewhere.  (A common issue is lack of good indexes for queries.)